# Как работает данный скрипт?

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При получении фокуса у элемента, беру его значение. Ввожу в тот же инпут какое-то значение и жму крестик, то есть отмена. В инпуте должно остаться прежнее значение.

Только объясните: как переменная может хранить значения предыдущих элементов, которые получили фокус? То есть если я меняю значения во всех инпутах и жму отмену, все значения сбрасываются в начальное состояние!

Вот такой вариант работает, правда не совсем понимаю, каким образом все же сбрасываются значения на дефолтные?

```
   //CANCEL ROW
    $('.for-clone input').focus(function(){
        $(this).closest('.for-clone').addClass('changed');
        var element = $(this);
        var elementVal = element.val();

        element.closest('.for-clone').find('.remove-column .cancel-ico').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            element.val(elementVal);
            $(this).closest('.for-clone').removeClass('changed');
        });
    });


<?php if($departments) : foreach($departments as $key => $department) : ?>
                    <form class="inline-form for-clone tr item changed" method="post" data-dep-id="<?php echo $department['id']; ?>">
                        <div class="td parent v_department">
                            <div class="wrapp-input edit">
                                <input type="text" class="input-val" name="department" placeholder="Department Name" value="<?php echo set_value('departments', $department['name']); ?>">
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="td parent v_manager">
                            <div class="wrapp-input select-wrapper edit">
                            <select  name="manager" class="input-val m-styled">
                                    <option value="">Department Manager</option>
                                        <?php if($users) : foreach($users as $user) : 
                                            $selected = $department['manager_id'] == $user['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $user['first_name'].'&nbsp;'.$user['second_name']; ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                                </select>                 
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="td parent v_country">
                            <div class="wrapp-input select-wrapper edit">
                                    <select  name="country" class="input-val m-styled">
                                        <option value="">Choose country</option>    
                                            <?php if($countries) : foreach($countries as $country) : 
                                                $selected = $department['country_id'] == $country['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $country['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $country['country_name']; ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                                </select>                 
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="td parent freedays-column v_free_days">
                            <div class="wrapp-input edit">
                                <input type="text" class="input-val" name="free_days" value="<?php echo set_value('free_days', $department['free_days']); ?>"> days
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="td edit-column">
                            <a href="#modal-forgot" class="modal-trigger link-simple show-holidays" data-modal="modal-forgot">Edit now</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="td save-column">
                            <div class="wrapp-btn-save">

                                <div class="preloader-wrapper xx-small active styled1">
                                <div class="spinner-layer">
                                  <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="gap-patch">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                    <div class="circle"></div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light ml-10 small save-this-row">
                                    <span class="save-position">Save it</span>
                                    <span class="wait-position">Wait</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="td remove-column">
                            <a href="#" class="trash-ico right"><span class="ico icon-trash "></span></a>                               
                            <a href="#" class="cancel-ico right"><span class="ico icon-cancel "></span></a>                             
                        </div>
                    </form>                 
            <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Comment: она и не хранит все значения, вы не можете реализовать? или в чем вопрос?

Comment: Тогда как по клику на крестик я получаю первоначальные значения всех инпутов которые получали фокус?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учитесь задавать вопросы.
К примеру загрузилась у вас страница с формой, в которой есть изначальные данные и вы хотите их восстанавливать, копируем эти данные и при необходимости восстанавливаем их. Выглядит приблизительно так.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var map = $('input:text').map(function(i,el){
        return $(this).val();
    });

  console.log(map);

$('.icon-cancel').click(function(){
            $('input:text').each(function(i){
              $(this).val(map[i]);
            });
        });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input class="input" value="01" type="text"><input class="input" value="04" type="text"><input class="input" value="05" type="text">
  <input class="icon-cancel" value="click" type="button" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ,как раз то что нужно.Но поясните пожалуйста как работает мой скрипт,каким образом сбрасываются все значения инпутов получившие фокус,как такое возможно? По идее должно храниться значение последнего элемента получившего фокус.Хотелось бы разобраться с этим моментом

Comment: я вашего кода не вижу.

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна возможность сброса значений полей на значения поумолчанию, то достаточно добавить атрибуты `value="значение по умолчанию"` для инпутов.

Для элементов списка `<option></option>`  нужно указывать атрибут `selected`.

Далее крестик сделать как кнопку типа `reset` стилизовав её как крестик при помощи CSS, или же оставить как у вас там сейчас (не вижу HTML, не знаю подробности) и при помощи JS вызывать сброс формы.

После сброса формы будут заданы значения поумолчанию для ваших элементов формы.

Вот рабочий пример:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input value="default value">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input value="other default value">
    <input type="reset">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а если строк с инпутами много? делать 100 форм?